# In a asp.net web api + angular, with refresh tokens... how do I automatically request a token before it expires

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity, token, owin

I started using [this tutorial](http://bitoftech.net/2014/06/09/angularjs-token-authentication-using-asp-net-web-api-2-owin-asp-net-identity/) to create a application sample, that uses refresh tokens. But in the application, the user have to click in a button to access the token and refresh it with a new token. I wish my application automatically request a new refresh token before it expires. How I can do this?

Comment: you can use such think https://gist.github.com/Mirodil/952e5932c284a2d205db

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should typically keep track of the time the token will expire and then request the new token before the expiration occurs. Requesting early in OAuth2.0 is acceptable.